Combining VictoriaMetrics and Thanos - VM for hot data, Thanos for lookback and federation?
I'm currently running a Prometheus + Thanos stack for metrics, and it's ... ok ... but it's outrageously memory-hungry. It also tends to fall on its face and OOM if more expensive queries are submitted, instead of simply taking longer to process them.
VictoriaMetrics is a lot more memory-efficient than Prometheus so I'd like to look at swapping it in. But I need federated query across several stores, and offloading of lookback metrics to an object store. Both of these are presently handled by Thanos Receive collecting data from Prometheus sidecars, feeding it into Thanos Store and accessing it with Thanos Query.
It's unclear if this model will translate well to use with VictoriaMetrics - if the VM TSDB is compatible with Thanos Sidecar. There are PromQL dialect issues to consider too.
But VM doesn't appear to support fan-out federated query or using object storage, so I can't just drop it in to replace Thanos too.
Is there a sensible, maintainable way to integrate VictoriaMetrics and Thanos, so that Thanos handles backlog retention and fan-out, but VictoriaMetrics is used instead of Prometheus for scraping, hot-data querying, recording rule processing etc?
If not, any advice for how to get Prometheus to execute more expensive queries without RAM usage that approaches the infinite? I've come from PostgreSQL where more expensive queries are just slower, as the RDBMS execution engine will use tempfiles and tapesorts and various other execution strategies to process datasets vastly in excess of available RAM. Prometheus ... just seems to want more RAM.
Edit: There are also data residency considerations, where EU user data may need to be physically stored in the EU, New Zealand user data physically stored in New Zealand, etc etc.


But VM doesn't appear to support fan-out federated query or using object storage, so I can't just drop it in to replace Thanos too.

In VM ecosystem fan-out queries aren't needed. Usually, Prometheus (or stateless scrape agents) is used for scraping and delivering metrics to central VM cluster. Data usually has about 30-60s freshness and can be queried  right away from central cluster, providing global query view.
Yes, VictoriaMetrics doesn't support object storage for historical data. But it is very efficient in terms of data compressing, so probably storing everything on disks would cost the same money and will provide better query performance.

Interesting. Similar approach to what Loki takes. This can run into issues with data residency laws and data-ownership requirements though.

These requirements can be handled by multitenancy policies - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/cluster-victoriametrics/#multitenancy. You can configure separate TTL for each tenant or a specific label-set. You can also isolate read access to tenants or label-sets. And you can delete data for a tenant or label-set.

That is helpful, but does not solve geographic data residence requirements. I'm not asking you to solve this for me either, just noting that sometimes it's necessary to have EU data live in the EU, US data live in the US, NZ data live in New Zealand, etc, and still be able to dashboard/alert on and query it centrally. It would be necessary to be able to define some kind of label selector for allocating tenant subsets to vmstorage node subsets. And probably some kind of fan-out querying to mitigate WAN latency with vmstorage access. So AFAICS VM can't really handle this right now.

Whether those data residency laws make much sense when the data isn't airgapped and can be queried in its entirety, without aggregation, from elsewhere is another matter. The rules are what they are. Presumably any capability like this would be VM enterprise only anyway (sensibly and justifiably so).
